# Online Porkchop Plotter

Tags: orbital-mechanics, delta-v, software

Is there an online tool available to calculate [porkchop plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porkchop_plot) at arbitrary resolutions?  Real world only please -- I am aware of the [tools available](http://alexmoon.github.io/ksp/) to do this for, say, KSP.
[image]

Comment: http://www.c3planner.com/ , http://www.orbithangar.com/searchid.php?ID=5418

Comment: Matlab script: [Interplanetary Pork Chop Plots](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39248-interplanetary-pork-chop-plots) and [Trajectory Optimization Tool](http://www.orbithangar.com/searchid.php?ID=5418) (this one suggested on Orbiter simulator site).

Comment: I wonder how often real rocket scientists get jealous of KSP players for all the handy numerical tools they have at their disposal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Technical University of Madrid offers an online [porkchop plotter application](http://sdg.aero.upm.es/index.php/online-apps/porkchop-plot) that I've used before. You may want to give it a try--I thought it was pretty good.

Here is what the entry form looks like:

[image: upm plotter entry form]

And here is one of the resulting plots:

[image: upm plotter chart]

Comment: From my alma mater!

Comment: Haha then congratulations and thanks are in order :)

Comment: And mine too! I can guarantee there's a lot of work behind that tool ;)

Comment: The question is for a link to a pork chop plotter online, I'm not sure what more I could add that would be essential?  I'm new to this so if you could show me what I could add I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @david_c I fleshed it out a little bit for you to give you and idea of what folks are looking for. Ideally, it could still use some more text--maybe a summary of the features or philosophy of the tool?

Comment: Can someone explain what the heck a porkchop plot is for the uninformed like me?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: A porkchop plot is created by running numerical simulations of a family of possible orbital trajectories with variations at intervals, so that you can see a set of contours representing the points where orbital variation is least or greatest, where delta-v (or perhaps time) are lowest, and so forth. This allows getting a good idea of the possibilities in an orbital situation without having to exhaustively simulate every possible path. They're called "porkchops" because the typical shape is much like a pork chop.