How exactly would nuclear thermal or nuclear electric propulsion enable short duration human missions to Mars?
Today (May 1, 2024) NASA Administrator Bill Nelson testified before the House Science, Space, and Technology Committee that nuclear thermal propulsion would enable us to go faster to Mars. He said:

If we can go fast, we don't have to stay on the surface for, on the first time, second time, a year or two, until the planets realign. ... we could go for a short visit.

My question is, how exactly does the more advanced propulsion enable a short visit? Ideally, I'd like to understand this in terms of a chart that shows mission duration versus some metric of the propulsion system's performance, such as its total delta-v or ISP. Also, is there a propulsion improvement threshold above which a whole new (and faster) approach to the mission becomes possible?
Update: The January 24, 2024 Braintruffle video Master the Complexity of Spaceflight provides some interesting background on the complexities of spaceflight.




related search term: porkchop plot

Linked, though not duplicate question https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57568/26356 since hopefully an answer here focuses on plots for low but continuous thrust rather than the classic porkchop instantaneous version.

It sounds like Bill Nelson is referring to a short stay mission profile, which can have a total trip duration of about a year and a half. The drawback being that most of the time is spent in space with as little as 30 days on Mars. And it takes a lot of energy, along with a Venus flyby. Mars enthusiasts routinely shout the idea down because of the limited time for exploration and because it requires new propulsion technology which they don't want to wait for. You may want to check if my suspicion is correct about what Nelson is proposing before trying to figure out performance thresholds etc.

Yes, I had the same thoughts. But your comment raises a good point. Venus flyby trajectories would need to be considered to properly answer this question. Do most online porkchop plot generators simplify to just the Sun, Earth, and Mars or do they also consider the influence of other planets such as Venus and Jupiter?

Your addition of the interplanetary transport network video (which you should add context to), and comment about Venus flyby trajectories, don't make sense to me.  Nuclear thermal propulsion is about going someplace fast.  ITN / flyby trajectories are trading extra trip duration for reduced energy and are exactly the opposite of what you're asking about.

While The video does mention ITN, that's not the only topic it covers. It helps to illustrate the complexities of orbital dynamics. As StevePemberton pointed out, the short stay mission profile involves a Venus flyby. It maybe more optimal according to NASA criteria (e.g. fewer provisions, maybe less radiation exposure). The nuclear  engine might be an onramp to a short stay mission profile but that profile could still include a flyby.

@ErinAnne - Venus flyby allows a short stay on Mars of 30-90 days instead of having to wait for Earth and Mars to align again before returning. However with current propulsion the total round trip is nearly two years, so not much improvement. However with higher propulsion (maybe nuclear?) and 30 day stay the round trip can be as low as thirteen months. From Nelson's quote it sounds like he might be suggesting wait for nuclear, then do the first one or two Mars missions short stay, which reduces risk (by some measures), then later missions can be long stay which does not require Venus flyby.

Note that I am not advocating short stay for the first Mars missions I am just saying it sounds like this might be what Nelson is talking about. The problem is all we have to go on at the moment is one sentence by the NASA admin. Who by the way also says we will have humans on the Moon year after next. I'm suggesting find out what he is referring to. The second problem is that short stay seems unpopular so it's hard to get details about it, the best I could find is on a Goddard web page from 2015.

Yes, I just want to understand the orbital mechanics that informs his (or NASA's) reasoning. Your Goddard link is very helpful - thanks!

The 2nd video is pretty amazing nonetheless.

@ErinAnne and others: Pork chop plots are not appropriate for low but continuous thrust missions. JPL calls the corresponding concept for such missions a "bacon plot", and such plots look very different from pork chop plots.


My question is, how exactly does the more advanced propulsion enable a short visit?

By enabling shorter and more flexible trips to and from Mars.
With conventional chemical propulsion, the trips to and from have to be timed exactly right. There are only a few times every other year where a trip to Mars is feasible using conventional chemical propulsion, and only a few times where a trip from Mars is feasible. This means waiting on Mars for a while until the timing is right. Vehicles that use chemical propulsion must drift (not fire thrusters) for the vast majority of the time on trips to and from Mars. This long coast period is an inherent necessity due to the low specific impulse of chemistry-based thrusters.
Nuclear powered electric propulsion has the promise of a much, much higher specific impulse. The high specific impulse electric engines come at a cost, which is the need for a lot of electric power. Solar powered electric engines have a ridiculously low thrust but an extremely high specific impulse. That's okay for lightweight uncrewed vehicles, but is not good for the much more massive vehicles needed to take humans to and from Mars. Nuclear powered vehicles might overcome that final issue.
Update
Various comments and answers have suggested pork chop plots. Those are completely inappropriate for low but continuous thrust missions. Pork chop plots are built by assuming an impulsive burns at the start and end, a ballistic coast in between, selecting departure and arrival dates, solving Lambert's for each choice, and then using a nice plotting tool to generate contours. The assumption of two impulsive burns does not apply to low but continuous thrust missions. Pork chop plots are relatively easy to create and are not vehicle specific. The solution to Lambert's problem for a selected pair of departure and arrival dates yields the energy per unit mass needed for the departure and arrival burns.
Bacon plots (JPL's term) for low but continuous thrust look very different from pork chop plots, are rather hard to construct, and are very vehicle-specific. Figure 4 in Woolley, Ryan C., et al. "Low-thrust trajectory Bacon plots for Mars mission design." (2019). shows a bacon plot overlaid with a pork chop plot. They are indeed completely different.

I don't disagree, but my question is more along the lines of "...but how exactly"? For example, could JEOD be used to generate plots like I described in this comment above and would those plots reveal how the shorter duration mission profiles (e.g. perhaps ones that use a Venus flyby) only become possible with higher ISP engines?

@phil1008 JEOD doesn't generate plots (Trick does, as does python). JEOD also does not do vehicle-specific modeling (nor does Trick). Since the optimization for low but continuous thrust missions is very vehicle specific, that would have to be a feature added by the simulation developer. Trick does have a nice Monte Carlo capability, and that combined with JEOD and the sim-specific vehicle thrust model could be used to optimize individual trajectories and then combined over multiple Monte Carlo analyses to generate bacon plots. This however seems like overkill to me.

@phil1008 With regard to "but exactly how" -- low but continuous thrust significantly broadens the time windows that dictate when transfer is feasible. The windows with a burn-coast-burn strategy (with the burns being impulsive, or nearly so) are rather narrow, less than a month wide every 25 months. With low but continuous thrust vehicles the feasible windows become several months wide (or even wider).

You make a good point that the duration of thrust is important for mission profile. You are correct that conventional chemical rockets, when used for interplanetary transfers, use short duration thrust and that SOLAR powered electric rockets use long, low-thrust burns. I’m not sure your assumption is correct that nuclear THERMAL rockets would also be used for low-trust trajectories.

Just like there is no such thing as a “small” nuclear explosion, I think there is a lower limit to the size of a nuclear thermal rocket. The NERVA nuclear thermal rocket (1969) had a thrust of 246,663N, about 25% of a SpaceX Merlin.

@Woody Perhaps one could fire for a brief time once every day or so to simulate the behavior of a long, low-thrust burn? That may not be feasible, though. The exhaust gas of a nuclear thermal rocket is also the coolant for a nuclear reactor, so any firing might need to include a lower-ISP cooldown time, which (if it is true) would make short firing times infeasible. Maybe I should ask a question about that....

@CharlesStaats ... there is a Pulsed Nuclear Thermal Rocket (see Wikipedia article by that name) which alternates between a low-thrust and high thrust state. It uses pulses of Prompt Neutrons which are very high energy and transmit that energy efficiently to H and He. Propellant temperatures higher than core temperatures are possible and thus extremely high ISP

This answer addresses Nuclear Electric Propulsion, but the NASA director (and OP) are talking about Nuclear Thermal Propulsion -- so the main body is more or less fine, but I think the update is completely wrong; pork chop plots are appropriate, because we're talking about a big burn, followed by 4 months of coast.

Answer: The higher specific impulse of nuclear propulsion, compared with chemical rockets,  allows use of interplanetary transfers which are quicker (but which require greater characteristic energy). This allows larger launch windows and more flexible mission planning. As a result, shorter (and longer) visits to Mars are possible.
The energy requirements for different interplanetary transfers are usually visualized using a Porkchop Plot, two of which are illustrated in the figure below from https://mars.nasa.gov/spotlight/porkchop-image01.html
The horizontal scale is departure date and the vertical scale is arrival date. Red lines join points with equal journey duration. Blue curves join departure/arrival pairs requiring equal characteristic energy. The smallest blue curves enclose the optimum (lowest energy) departure/arrival local minima. This is often referred to as a "launch window".
Any deviation from this local minima requires the rocket to provide more energy, reducing payload. Nuclear rockets can meet this demand for more energy, allowing departure/arrival within a larger blue curve. In effect, a larger launch window.
The higher specific impulse of nuclear propulsion over chemical rockets could allow greater payload, faster transfers or some combination thereof.
Faster transfers allow shorter visits by giving a wider choice of arrival and departure times at the Mars end. The mission is not limited to the interval between local minima.


I think that porkchop plots for both directions with some annotations that show how the total mission duration can be shortened (including the stay on the surface of Mars) might help to answer my question.

@phil1008 ... you are correct. This was addressed in https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/online-porkchop-plotter

Yes, saw that but the link to the online tool seems to be broken.

@phil1008 ... you are looking for an example Mars departure porkchop for illustrative purposes? If you can't find one, just make one up modelled on Earth departure. You are not planning an actual mission. Draw curves centered on an arbitrary local minima and play with different launch/arrival coordinates. The principle of greater rocket performance allowing greater flexibility of mission design will be apparent.

I think (speculating a bit here) this is going to require a porkchop plots that consider Venus flybys, and probably Jupiter's influence as well. Also, we would need to see the return plot's departure date axis aligned with the outbound plot's arrival date axis so that we can figure out how long the stay on Mars would be. So the return plot's axes would need to be be swapped.

I would speculate that for nuclear-based propulsion the graphs will not necessary look porkchop-like. For thermal nuclear propulsion with short acceleration period (up to several days) - yes, they will, becsuse most of the flight is still inertial. But for continous nuclear-electric propulsion the graphs can look wery different (but I can't tell how exactly)

I agree with @Heopps that a pork chop plot may not be appropriate (or at least will look very different) for a continuous thrust trajectory. Solving this problem is very difficult as it's essentially an infinite dimensional nonlinear optimization problem, and is computationally expensive, even with discretization. Papers and books are still being written on this topic to this day.

In comparison, a single point on a pork chop plot is easy to solve for as these plots assume two impulsive burns, one at the start to place the vehicle on a conic section that takes the vehicle from Earth to Mars and another at the end. This essentially requires solving Lambert's problem (which is easy), and then using a nice plotting tool.

It turns out that this is nowhere close to the right answer. Pork chop plots simply do not apply to low but continuous thrust missions.

Whether relevant for continuous nuclear thrust or not, this is the first time I've understood what's plotted on a porkchop plot, so kudos for the clear explanation.

Who keeps upvoting this obviously wrong answer?

My tuppence; I think David Hammen's answer and the ensuing comments are in the right, I am only trying to add a different perspective. This isn't a full answer in its own right, in fact it is just a series of questions addressing part of the "How ..." concept.
It might be that "nuclear thermal propulsion would enable us to go faster" just means "a bit faster, depending on the mass of the vehicle".
Looking at this another way, this is a long way around but it is meant to appeal to non-astrodynamicists:

what acceleration (not thrust) would be so high that the gravity well looks just like a ripple? Let's not bother to answer it yet, it just removes an important complication from the next bit of the thought experiment.

...which is

what acceleration does our vehicle need to get to Mars if it were to accelerate for half the journey and decelerate for the next half of the journey, stay there for a bit and then come back, all in some arbitrary and convenient elapsed time? Its still not a back of the envelope calc as the positions of Earth and Mars are constantly changing, ignore that too if you want.
what is that thrust in real world terms for our imaginary vehicle? Is it still huge? Can we close the design for an imaginary vehicle with the thrust and Isp touted for present day nuclear schemes?
what happens when we factor back that the gravity well will not be just a ripple with current projected acceleration (i.e. nuclear-(something) thrust with plausible vehicle size plus rocket equation)?

Once again,sorry no actual answers. Where we are going is that as the vehicle scales up to manage the support services needed for both crew and the high-thrust/high Isp engine, the resulting acceleration might mean we are still in what we consider the low-thrust regime, a long spiral, however there "might" be some way to contrive for it to be "a bit" faster than an impulsive transfer.

Regarding your point #1, the Sun's gravity at 1 au is ~6 mm/s^2.
